# How to tell Excel what date format to read cells as WITHOUT changing the cell content?

Tags: microsoft-excel, date, locale

I'm opening a CSV file which contains dates in the European format, dd/mm/yyyy. When opening it with Excel, Excel thinks they are in the American mm/dd/yyyy format, which makes sorting/filtering just plain wrong.

If I now select those columns and tell them that their format is the former, Excel now flips days and months, because it apparently assumes that I want to *convert* the format.

I don't want to *convert* the locale, I want Excel to *read* it as a different locale. How can I do that? All articles/superuser questions I read are about actually converting the locale, which in my case just completely messes the file up.

This feels like a similar problem to Excel assuming a certain separator in a CSV and reading the file in wrong, which I managed to fix by prepending the CSV file with sep=myseparator. Is there something similar I can do here, and tell it which date format it should assume?

Comment: Do not **OPEN** the file. **IMPORT** the file using either the legacy import wizard or `Get & Transform` (aka `Power Query`). When you do that you will be presented with a dialog where you can specify the format of the dates in the incoming CSV file.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Ah, that's weird. Thanks. I'm not sure where the legacy import wizard is, but if I click on Data -> Load I can get some PowerQuery UI (which seems a bit overkill for such a honestly trivial problem but I guess Excel is like that with some things...), but if I specify my column type like so `Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"dateOp", type date}, ...` it just says "Error", weirdly. Is there a way for me to tell it something like `type date dd/mm/yyyy`?

Comment: And if I pass some kind of locale like "en-IE" (which is also dumb because really I only want the date format to change...) it does not show me the error anymore, so I assume it sorts it correctly, but it DISPLAYS it as mm/dd/yyyy. Which isn't a huge problem but annoying nonetheless.

Comment: You can change the locale, then import the file, finally changing the locale back. The imported dates will not change in the imported sheet.

Comment: PQ will **always** display dates according to your Windows Regional Settings.  You have no control over this. (You could create a text column formatted how you want, but when you export it to Excel, they won't be real dates anymore). In Excel you can format however you want.  If passing the locale causes an issue with your other columns (pretty unlikely), then add an extra step. First transform that column to Text; then add a step where you transform just that date column per your culture.

Comment: Regarding the legacy wizard, it is version dependent. A simple search returns this [article from Microsft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/data-import-and-analysis-options-3ea52160-08bc-45ac-acd9-bc4a11bcc2a2)